# Clicking on a P Tag happens to fast in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following Jquery:

```
$('.agendaNav').click(function(event){
    $(this).find('.rightArrow').attr('src', '/images/arrowdown.png');
    if($('.agendaDay').is(':hidden')){
        $('.agendaDay').show();
    } else {
        $('.agendaDay').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<p class="agendaNav"><img src="/images/arrowright.png" class="rightArrow" /> WEEK AT A GLANCE</p>
```

What happens is the .agendaDay class hides but it get's shown again extremely quickly no matter how fast I click the element.

Any idea why it's not working?  Maybe I have to make it an a tag?

Comment: I don't understand this at all - in your JS, you're never showing the `agendaDay` element ever, you only hide it. and where is the element that has the class `agendaDay`? Can you post a working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or JSbin or similar?

Comment: Could you please ellaborate your example with the code that contains `.agendaDay`. Also do you mean to use an if/else that does the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running the same code in both the `if` and the `else`. Try this on for size:

```
$('.agendaNav').click(function(event){
    $(this).find('.rightArrow').attr('src', '/images/arrowdown.png');
    if($('.agendaDay').is(':hidden')){
        $('.agendaDay').show(); // <------------- change this line
    } else {
        $('.agendaDay').hide();
    }
});
```

Also, [there's a jQuery function for that](http://api.jquery.com/toggle):

```
$('.agendaNav').click(function(event){
    $(this).find('.rightArrow').attr('src', '/images/arrowdown.png');
    $('.agendaDay').toggle();
});
```

Intent clearer: check. More concise: check. More efficient: check. Less room for programmer error: **check**.

Comment: Oh shoot that's the way I had it I tried the toggle but it still has the same problem, see here: http://icuc2011.com/agenda  Click on "Week At a Glance"

Comment: I tried $(this).next() and $(this).next('.agendaDay') and it doesn't seem to select it.

Comment: You're right. I thought there was a `.agendaDay` after each `.agendaNav` that you wanted to toggle. The original code I suggested in my answer works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/X3KeP/

Comment: It's working now, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong at first but what you did worked, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted out.